# java preferences API on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, preferences

From the java preferences API documentation, I see this:

> The data is stored persistently in an
>   implementation-dependent backing
>   store.

Is `java.util.prefs` available for use in GAE/J?
If so, does it use the datastore for persistence? Something else? Magic?

I've done the standard googling and such before asking this question, and couldn't find much. Any info is appreciated.

-tjw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since it is not on the [whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html)

Comment: Any ideas for a similar preferences library? And yea, ok, sorry for the uninformed question.

Comment: Is this just to store config settings?  Probably just add a properties file resource.  If it is something that needs to be updated, probably store it in the data store.